# Data over artisan bakery sales and earnings

Tags: data-request

This is a questions about skillful master bakers who sell their wonderful artisan breads and baguettes to famous bakeries, farmer's markets and similar places excluding any patisserie items.

Is there any data available on traditional bakeries/bakers' sale of breads, earnings across american/european cities ?

Comment: So, you want to exclude all industrially-produced bread from the data, right? And also exclude bread which is produced by artisans but sold in supermarkets?

Comment: BLS tracks food prices in the U.S., but they average over the whole country and only track 5 'bread' categories (none of which is 'artisan') : http://www.bls.gov/data/ (look under 'average price data')

Comment: Nicolas I am looking an artisan baker can create and sell primarily to end customer. It would be great if there is data on selling artisan breads to retail shops. So yes I am looking for any of those except industrial bread.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen the detailed data you are looking for. But, there are several datasets of farmer's markets in the US. Some of them contain contact information and general categories of goods sold.

The USDA American Marketing Service (AMS) maintains a dataset of 8,200 farmers markets in the US: http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/

I have my own version of this dataset converted into a Linked CSV format: http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.1/USDA/AMS/index.php

The Federation of New York also has a published list of farmer's markets and details in the State of New York. This can be found at:
http://www.nyfarmersmarket.com/farmers-market-profiles/markets/markets.html

CalPoly also has a research dataset (available to the public) on one years worth of sales/goods from a bakery chain in 4 states:
https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/datasets/wiki/ExtendedBakery

The UC Irvine Machine Learning Repository also keeps a restaurant related research dataset covering 130 restaurants:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Restaurant+%26+consumer+data#